# Angular project doesn't shows changes

Tags: angular, typescript

Angular doesn't show any changes, just the base html angular provides when you run ng serve for the first time. Even though that code was erased from the project, it's the one that gets displayed.

Im using Angular 12.0.5, I've tried to run

```
ng serve --live-reload
```

and

```
ng serve --watch=true
```

but it doesn't seem to work, any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try running the following command :

```bash
sudo ng serve
```

If it will work, there must be some access related issues for angular on your system.

On a side note: no need to provide any flag/options to `ng serve` ( as per your question ).
For me, direct command `ng serve` works like a charm and it auto build any new changes.

Please let me know the outcome.